# class not registered on IIS

Tags: windows, windows-8, iis, asp.net

I have windows 8 (x64) with IIS8. IIS was working fine but suddenly when i try to browse anything from IIS, it prompt's a message box says,

> class not registered!

[image]

i have checked the default port is free. i have also a site which is bonded to the 8081 port also shows same error message. i have .net 2.0,3.5 and 4.5 installed from windows feature.

I have uninstalled and then installed the IIS from windows feature but error remains same. :(

can anyone please tell me what is going on?

Comment: http://cavemansblog.wordpress.com/2008/06/23/iis-internal-server-error-class-not-registered/ try that solution and let me know, i can't test it as don't have Win 8.

Comment: @avirk asptxn.dll is not available on windows 8

Comment: @avirk for this error messagebox there is no windows event log is generated.

Comment: Someone give me a minus vote. may i know why this minus for?

Comment: How are you 'browsing' IIS exactly?  "it prompt's a message box"  What gives you the prompt, your browser or the IIS Manager UI (, or something else)?  Exactly what actions do you perform to make this popup appear?  Have you tried a new test site with a simple HTML document in it?

Comment: @techie007 i have click to the default website/my custom site and then click to the browse button on the right side of the IIS manager and then the messagebox is appear. i think it is simple enough to browse only the localhost to test. is't it?

Comment: @techie007 may be you missed it. i have mentioned in my question that i have tested with different site with different port.

Comment: If you browse to the site using an actual browser, does it work as expected? Is IE set as your default browser?  Have you tried repairing/reinstalling IE?

Comment: @techie007 as i am not with the buggy machine right now. will notify soon. thanks

Comment: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/5f141b3d-54d0-4dc6-8e8d-38f220231f23/iexplorerexe-class-not-registered?forum=ieitprocurrentver

Comment: @techie007 strange! i can successfully browse the hosted site in IIS by typing the URL into the browser. but why i cant broser by clicking to the browse button on IIS manager? any Idea?

Comment: Perhaps try reinstalling the IIS Management feature.

Comment: @techie007 I have already mentioned in the question that: "I have uninstalled and then installed the IIS from windows feature but error remains same. :("